# How to turn a variable into a dictionary item

Tags: ansible, ansible-facts

I am struggling with what I believe is the simplest of tasks. I want to take a variable `v` and turn that into a dictionary where

```yaml
v: ValueofV
```

The end goal is to write that dictionary to a JSON file that contains a list of variables, with `key: value` where key name is always a variable name, so for variables `a`, `b`, `c`, ... I should end up with:

```json
{
  "a": "a_val",
  "b": "v_val",
  "c": "c_val"
}
```

I've tried building lists with_items, e.g.

```yaml
- name: Var3
  set_fact:
    node_state4: "{{ node_state4 | default({}) | combine({ item : item })}}"
  with_items:
    - requested_node_count
    - added_node_count
```

But, that makes the value the string name. If I make the second item `{{ item }}` it fails.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to access a variable value via a string representation of its name, you need to use the [`vars` lookup](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/vars_lookup.html).

So your task should be:

```yaml
- set_fact:
    node_state4: >-
      {{ 
        node_state4 
          | default({}) 
          | combine({ item: lookup('vars', item) })
      }}
  loop:
    - requested_node_count
    - added_node_count
```

---

Given this the two tasks:

```yaml
- set_fact:
  node_state4: >-
      {{ 
        node_state4 
          | default({}) 
          | combine({ item: lookup('vars', item) })
      }}
  loop:
    - requested_node_count
    - added_node_count
  vars:
    requested_node_count: foo
    added_node_count: bar

- debug:
    var: node_state4
```

This yields:

```
TASK [set_fact] **********************************************************
ok: [localhost] => (item=requested_node_count)
ok: [localhost] => (item=added_node_count)

TASK [debug] *************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => {
    "node_state4": {
        "added_node_count": "bar",
        "requested_node_count": "foo"
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Benoit, I am accepting this over the other solution as this is out of the box.

Answer (score 1):

Use filter [*community.general.dict_kv*](https://ansible.fontein.de/collections/community/general/docsite/filter_guide_abstract_informations_dictionaries.html#dictionaries) e.g.

```yaml
  _dict: "{{ v|community.general.dict_kv('v') }}"
```

gives

```yaml
  _dict:
    v: ValueofV
```

---

Given the list of the variables

```yaml
    rnodes: [a, b, c]
    a: a_val
    b: b_val
    c: c_val
```

iterate the list and create the dictionary, e.g.

```yaml
    - set_fact:
        _dict: "{{ _dict|d({})|
                   combine(lookup('vars', item)|
                           community.general.dict_kv(item)) }}"
      loop: "{{ rnodes }}"
```

gives

```yaml
  _dict:
    a: a_val
    b: b_val
    c: c_val
```

---

The next option is to *extract* the variables and use filters [*dict* and *zip*](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/devel/user_guide/playbooks_filters.html#combining-items-from-multiple-lists-zip-and-zip-longest), e.g. the task below gives the same result

```yaml
    - set_fact:
        _dict: "{{ dict(rnodes|zip(_vals)) }}"
      vars:
        _vals: "{{ rnodes|map('extract', vars) }}"
```